# Am I misunderstanding the docs, or is Qt.createQmlObject (almost) useless?

Tags: qt, qml, loading, qtquick2

From [the Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method):

> Note that this function returns immediately, and therefore may not work if the qml string loads new components (that is, external QML files that have not yet been loaded). If this is the case, consider using Qt.createComponent() instead.

But as far as I know, *all* QML files are "external", and any of them may have its load delayed arbitrarily long.

E.g. if I do this:

```
Qt.createQmlObject('\
    import QtQuick 2.0\n\
    Rectangle { }
    ',
    parentObject,
    "myRect");
```

What happens if Rectangle has not been loaded by the time I execute this code? By this logic any code that uses `Qt.createQmlObject` with imports in the passed string is risky. So we should always use `Qt.createComponent` instead.

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding these docs, but I don't know what the right interpretation of them is.

Comment: `createComponent()` is different, it doesn't work from an in-memory string, it requires an uri to an external file. Here async loading is allowed, plus you have the choice between sync and async.

Comment: @ddriver: I realize that. What I'm saying is that `Qt.createComponent` is a possible replacement for `Qt.createQmlObject`, although it loads from an uri to an external file, instead of an in-memory string. And it doesn't have the fatal problem that `Qt.createQmlObject` appears to have.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I suspect createQmlObject will be fine as long as the files are available locally and the modules are in the import path. If you rely on generated code just save the strings as files and use createComponent just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if Rectangle has not been loaded by the time I execute this code? By this logic any code that uses Qt.createQmlObject with imports in the passed string is risky. So we should always use Qt.createComponent instead.

For library types (like Rectangle), they are immediately available once the import statement has been reached somewhere. Your containing document likely contains such an import, to present a UI, so Rectangle would already be available to createQmlObject - you wouldn't really have much of a problem there.

For anything loaded on disk, too, it isn't a very complex process to fetch those, so you should (according to some quick testing and code reading) be fine. As I understand it, the mention in the documentation is more warning about cases where you might try load imports over the network, as those may block for an indeterminate amount of time. The documentation could be clearer, I agree. Please consider filing a documentation bug at [bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io).

This having been said, personally, I would suggest that you avoid createQmlObject if you can, and use Qt.createComponent, `Component {}`, etc, for a number of reasons:

- createQmlObject's performance is not great in comparison (as it has to create a component each time, rather than reusing one)
- you lose warnings at load time, and trade them for warnings at runtime (although createComponent suffers the same problem, and this may be an acceptable tradeoff if performance is a concern)
- as you point out with this question, it does have additional limitations